# How does TensorFlow compute the gradient of vgg19.preprocess_input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, automatic-differentiation, style-transfer

I am following the tutorial on [neural style transfer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/style_transfer). The style transfer is done by minimizing a loss function with respect to an image (initialized with the content image). What confuses me is the following piece of code:

```
preprocessed_input = tf.keras.applications.vgg19.preprocess_input(inputs)
```

which is part of the `call` method in the `StyleContentModel` class. How does TensorFlow know the gradient of this operation? I have checked if this operation has a gradient function using `get_gradient_function` in the module `tensorflow.python.framework.ops`, and as far as I can tell it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple, the function internally uses symbolic tensor operations that are differentiable. TensorFlow can compute gradients through functions that internally use TensorFlow operations, there is no need to manually define a gradient for each function.

You can confirm by looking at the code of that function [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/bc89834ed36935ab4a4994446e34ff81c0d8e1b7/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py#L152), specially if you look at the `_preprocess_symbolic_function` [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/bc89834ed36935ab4a4994446e34ff81c0d8e1b7/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py#L93) which is using normal scalar operations and Keras backend functions (which are just TensorFlow functions in `tf.keras`).

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the model or gradients. What this function does is  scale the input images so the pixels are in the range from -1 to +1. This is a common requirement for many models used in transfer learning like VGG and MobileNet. If you use the ImageDataGenerator it has a parameter preprocessing_function which the generator calls to preprocess the images. Make sure if you preprocess the training images you do the same for the test and validation images.

Comment: You are not answering the question here.